# Apigility - How to use Doctrine ORM Module from ZF2 command line

Tags: php, orm, zend-framework2, doctrine, laminas-api-tools

Hi i'm new with [Apigility](https://apigility.org/). Im trying to configure doctrine-orm-module. When i tried to run the command below and getting this error

```
$ cd /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin
$ php doctrine-module.php
```

Error is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.cli' in /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php(51): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('doctrine.cli')
#1 {main} thrown in /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 529

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.cli' in /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php(51): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('doctrine.cli')
#1 {main} thrown in /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 529
```

I followed the installation guide on [DoctrineORMModule's readme.md](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run doctrine-module cli directly inside the bin folder. DoctrineModule already binds related console routes to the application if it's configured correctly.

Try this:

```
$ cd /var/www/apigility/zf-apigility-skeleton
$ php public/index.php orm:info
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that works! i spent hours triyng to config. Doctrine.

Comment: [Exception]                                                                                                       
  You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or  
   mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.

Comment: how do I auto-create mapped Doctrine ORM entities without the cli ?