# creating mapped ORM Entities without the cli?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I'm working on an apiglity project that uses zend framework 2 and the doctrine.

i included in local.config.php of my zf2 project the following code:

```
return array(
 'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'port'     => '3306',
                'user'     => '<username>',
                'password' => '<password>',
                'dbname'   => '<db>',
            )
        )
    )
),
);
```

in my main module's configuration file (module.config.php) I included the following code:

```
 'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I read the following URL:
http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/zend-framework-2-generate-doctrine-entities-from-existing-database-using-doctrinemodule-and-doctrineormmodule/

and it says that to create Entities from my Database I need to use `vendor/bin/doctrine-module`.

When I try to execute doctrine-module I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.cli' in /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php(51): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('doctrine.cli')
#1 /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module(4): include('/mnt/storage/ho...')
#2 {main}
thrown in /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 529

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.cli' in /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php(51): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('doctrine.cli')
#1 /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module(4): include('/mnt/storage/ho...')
#2 {main}
thrown in /mnt/storage/home/ufk/projects/myalcoholist-apigility/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 529
```

by reading the following stack overflow question:
[Apigility - How to use Doctrine ORM Module from ZF2 command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128660/apigility-how-to-use-doctrine-orm-module-from-zf2-command-line)

I understood that the doctrine-module client is not necessary and I should execute

```
php public/index.php orm:info
```

in order to see the status of doctrine.

when executing this I get the following error message:

```
[Exception]                                                                                                       
You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or  
mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.
```

this is because I created the Entities folder and it's empty.

now the question is, how do I create Entities based on database if I can't use the doctrine-module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'paths' => array(**DIR** . '/../src/' . **NAMESPACE** . '/Entity')

I don't understand this path.. Can you try to a simple path?
For example

```
__DIR__.'/../src/YourModule/Entity'
```

And write your entity into the YouModule module, in src/YouModule/Entity

Comment: hi, my namespace is the name of the module, so the path is correct. the problem is that the directory is empty because i didn't generate any Entity classes. the question is how to generate them

Comment: But your directory is empty?! Have yo create a table mapping? genera entities create getter and setter and validate your map http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-product

Comment: i didn't create table mapping because i don't want to manually create table mapping for each table. i have tons, looking for a way to create them automatically based on my database

Comment: I don't remember if DoctrineModule support this flow but you can try with php public/index.php orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml /path/to/mapping-path-converted-to-yml (or your mapping driver)

Comment: i get Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES). i did define credentials for doctrine in local.config.php, why doesn't it uses that information ?

Comment: i need to add doctrine.local-development.php and add the database data there. doctrine ignores default configuration files but accept <file>.local-development.php

Comment: yeap. thanks a lot you've been a great help. I was stuck on this for 3 frustrating days